# Concatenating various characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a series of ID numbers like this

```
    ABC/12345/2012
    DEF/67891/2013
    GHI/23456/2014
    KLM/78911/2014
```

I need to change them so they look like this

```
    12-12345
    13-67891
    14-23456
    14-78911
    14-6634
```

The below works to a degree but I have a few that only have 4 numbers in, they should be proceeded by a zero.

```
   SELECT RIGHT(ID, 2)+'-'+RIGHT(SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('/', ID, 1)-1, LEN(ID)-7), 5)

    12-12345
    13-67891
    14-23456
    14-78911
    14-/6634
```

So I need 14-/6634 to look like 14-06634

Comment: You should probably try doing it in your application code

Comment: Always that format? substring combined with concat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your column name is ID, and length of each substrings between the '/' characters is not variable (ABC = 3, 12345 = 5, 2012 = 4):

```
SELECT RIGHT(ID, 2)+'-'+RIGHT(SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('/', ID, 1)-1, LEN(ID)-7), 5)
```

Based on your main post edit:

```
SELECT RIGHT(ID, 2)+'-'+REPLACE(RIGHT(SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('/', ID, 1)-1, LEN(ID)-7), 5), '/', '0')
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you, though it's now bought up another issue, which I initially hadn't considered, which I will edit in my opening post

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, would never have gotten close to that myself

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @tmp varchar(50) = 'ABC/12345/2012'

select SUBSTRING(@tmp, len(@tmp) - 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@tmp,CHARINDEX('/',@tmp)+1,LEN(@tmp))
```

it gives you

```
12-12345/2012
```

and now you have to remove /2012

Answer (score 0):

If your data is fixed format, then you can use [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

Sample execution with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (TestData VARCHAR (50));

INSERT INTO @TestTable (TestData)
SELECT 'ABC/12345/2012' UNION
SELECT 'DEF/67891/2013' UNION
SELECT 'GHI/23456/2014' UNION
SELECT 'KLM/78911/2014'

SELECT RIGHT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(TestData, '/', '.'), 1), 2) + '-' +
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(TestData, '/', '.'), 2) AS TestData
FROM @TestTable
```

Result:

```
TestData
--------
12-12345
13-67891
14-23456
14-78911
```